# Using Kotlin's raw strings for sql insert in Spring JDBC namedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-jdbc

Is it possible to use Kotlin's raw strings for sql inserts with the namedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring JDBC?

```
val insertCommand = """INSERT INTO sqluser.my_table 
    (number_field, text_field, date_field, decimal_field, null_text_field) 
    VALUES (:number_field, :text_field, :date_field, :decimal_field, :null_text_field) 
"""

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(insertCommand, namedParameters)
```

I receive this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO sqluser.my_table 
              (number_field, text_field, date_field, decimal_field, null_text_field) 
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
              ]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=
, DRIVER=4.32.28
```

If I concatenate single strings, it works:

```
val insertCommand = "INSERT INTO sqluser.my_table " +
           " (number_field, text_field, date_field, decimal_field, null_text_field) " +
           " VALUES (:number_field, :text_field, :date_field, :decimal_field, :null_text_field) "
```

Does Spring JDBC have problems resolving the placeholders? Or is there anything else I need to consider?

Comment: A string is a string; whether the code uses a simple string literal, or a raw string to create it — or whether it uses dollar interpolation or not — it creates a String object in each case.  So the update() method can't tell the difference.  Instead, you might want to check what the string _contains_ in each case.  (Try using the #1 debugging tool: printing out the value in the two cases, and checking how they differ.)

Comment: @gidds Thank you very much. The debugging tool #1 shows me that the difference is in the number of rows used.  If I write the raw string completely in one line it works.

Comment: I think I found it: val insertCommand = """insert into my_table ......".replace('\n', ' ')

Comment: Ah, so it's the newlines. (I guessed that.)  You might find it easier to use [trimIndent()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim-indent.html) (or [trimMargin()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim-margin.html)), which are intended for this sort of thing.

Comment: @gidds I think neither trimMargin() nor trimIndent() removes the newlines. I just played through it in the Kotlin playground. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the docs.  (And if I'd been writing a full answer, I'd have tried it first :-)  Using `replace()` is fine.  Another option is `.filter{ it != '\n' }` (assuming the lines are indented).  If you're doing this a lot, you could write your own function for clarity, e.g. `fun String.convertNewlines() = replace('\n', ' ')`.

Comment: @gidds I have now implemented it as an extension function and it works fine. Thanks again.